# Получить имя заголовка

Tags: jquery

Есть код

```js
var name = this;
var name = $(this).attr("href");
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="#main" class="clickmenu">
    <span class="material-icons">home</span>
    <h4>Главная</h4>
  </a>
  <a href="#home" class="active clickmenu">
    <span class="material-icons">cottage</span>
    <h4>Дом</h4>
  </a>
</div>
```

в переменной main содержится текст в виде #main
Нужно при клике получать в переменную содержимое тега h4
Не пойму как правильно написать.
Спасибо!

Comment: Спасибо! Как скажите!

Comment: *как скажЕте...

Comment: Не ясно куда должен быть совершён клик и какой текст куда класть, т.к. никаких переменных main в коде нет.... что за код странный - тоже интересно

Comment: Пойду учиться!!!

Comment: Удаляю комменты выше) верю, что ТС реально пошел учится и у него все будет хорошо) Желаю Удачи!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `h4` находится внутри `a`, этот элемент можно найти с помощью метода [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Чтобы получить текст элемента можно воспользоваться методом [`.text`](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

В итоге код может выглядеть так:

```
var content = $(this).find('h4').text();
```

Comment: Спасибо, Вам огромное!